# Fetch data from database and send to mail via phpMailer

Tags: php, sql, phpmailer

I am trying to fetch data posted to the database and send to mail using phpMailer.
below is the code to do fetching and sending the same data.

The issue is, I am not able to fetch and and send

```
<?php

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
         $mail->SMTPDebug = false;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
   // $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.bluehost.com');  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username   = '****@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
        $mail->Password   = '*****';                               // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port       = 587; 
        $mail->addAddress('****@gmail.com', 'title');
        require_once("config.php");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM order";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $mail->setFrom($email, 'title');
        $mail->Subject = 'Test email!';
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $message ='
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<table border='1'>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($row as $field => $value) {  foreach($row as $value) {
        echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";  
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        '
        $mail->Body = ($message);

       if( !$mail->send() ) echo 'wrong';
        else echo 'Mail sent';

}
?>
```

The results should be, the data fetched and send to database with table container

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, but why are you echoing and using loops inside a string? I suggest modifying your `$message ` first. Regardless, `phpmailer` should tell you an error if you used `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; ` instead

Comment: Your PHP code inside the string will be read as text, not as PHP.  Also, your're missing the `;` after `$message = '...'` which should throw a parse/syntax error. While developing, make sure you have error reporting set to E_ALL and display errors turned on so you'll see the errors straight away.

Comment: Look at the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer.